# how to define an array of octet string with undefined size?

Tags: c

How to define an array of octet string on C ?

I tried like that `U08 array[] = {(0xff,0xff,0xff),(0x2f,0x1f,0x2f)}` but it dosen't work.

```
array[0] = {0xff,0xff,0xff}
array[1] = {0x2f,0x1f,0x2f} 
etc ..
```

Comment: What are your octet/byte strings? Are they always 3 bytes long or can they have different lengths? (I guess the "undefined size" from the title refers to the number of strings.)

Comment: It's unclear what bytes exactly your array should contain and how long the array is. Please [edit] and clarify. Also tell us what `U08` is for completeness, so we don't need to guess.

Comment: @M Oehm my byte strings are just U08 elements and they have always the same size. @Jabberwocky the long of the array is not important.

Comment: @stackanonym please show us the definition of `U08`, it's not a standard C type.

Comment: @stackanonym and shouldn't it be `array[1] = {0x1f,0x1f,0x1f}`? Read your question again carefully.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's just an example you can put 0x1f or 0x2f or what ever you want

Comment: @stackanonym your question being unclear, the sample should be accurate at least. But you still didn't tell us what the `U08` type is. Without knowing that, the question can't be answered.

Comment: The length of the array is important to the question , e.g. if they are all the same length then it is a simpler case

Comment: @M.M there is two ways to initialize the array of byte string either 
U08 array[2][3] = {(0xff,0xff,0xff),(0x2f,0x1f,0x2f)} either 
U08 array[2][3] = {"\x2f\x02\53\x1f","\x2f\x02\53\x1f"}

Comment: @stackanonym `\5` is illegal

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you'll need a 2D array for what you're trying to do.

Try `U08* array[] = {{0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, {0x1f, 0x1f, 0x1f}};`

EDIT: As per comments below, 
try this if you're aware of the octet string size
`U08 array[][3] = {{0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, {0x1f, 0x1f, 0x1f}};`

Else, this seems to be the good solution
`U08* array[] = { (U08[]){0xff,0xff,0xff}, (U08[]){0x1f,0x1f,0x1f} }`

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

You should try something like: `U08 array[][3] = {{0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, {0x1f, 0x1f, 0x1f}};`

Comment: That doesn't work. You must specify the second dimension of the array `U08 array[][3]` if you want to use this initialization.

Comment: ... or compound literals `U08* array[] = { (U08[]){0xff,0xff,0xff}, (U08[]){0x1f,0x1f,0x1f} }` (assuming C>=99, as I now do)

Comment: Your second is an error, it would be good to edit the answer to be correct. There is no need to try and preserve some kind of edit history in the answer (anyone can read the edit history)

Comment: thanks for all your response but i need to initialize exactly an array with byte string neither a 2D array nor a pointer to an array like dave_thompson_085 proposed. i guess my demand is not possible.

Comment: @stackanonym To know if what you want is impossible we need to know what you want, your questiojn is very unclear. Please edit your question and show more information. What bytes _exactly_ should your array contain? What's an _"octet string"_?

Comment: @Jabberwocky i clarified that my array should contatin an U08 elements. an octet string is a byte string here is an example u08 array[]={0xff,0xff} => this is a byte string of 2 elements, i guess it's clear

Comment: @stackanonym still unclear, maybe you should tell us the memory content byte per byte `array` should contain: E.g. `array[0] = ?, array[1] = ?, array[2] = ?, etc`. Tell us what should be at the `?`s. Edit your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok it's like array[0] = {0xff,0xff,0xff}
                                         array[1] = {0x2f,0x1f,0x2f}
                                         .
                                         .